# should I just set SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity for maximum performance?

Tags: c#, pinvoke

Am I correct that if I need maximum performance, and I have trusted library I should just set [SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.suppressunmanagedcodesecurityattribute.aspx) attribute to all Dll imports I have?

I.e. convert such import:

```
    [DllImport("srl.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    private static extern string ErrorMsg(int ErrCode);
```

to such import:

```
    [DllImport("srl.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi), SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
    private static extern string ErrorMsg(int ErrCode);
```

everywhere.

Are there any reasons not to set SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity?

Comment: You can also set `SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity` on the *class* containing your P/Invoke method declarations, and it will apply to all methods declared within that class.